# How can I get date in application run by node.js?

Tags: node.js

Do I have to manually run `date` command using child_process and fetch the result from it to get the date? Is there any other way using node?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You do that as you would in a browser:

```js
    var datetime = new Date();
    console.log(datetime);
```

Comment: No.  Check it in nagavitor and then in node, the response will be different: "new Date().toLocaleDateString('pt-br')"

Answer (score 44):

```js
    var datetime = new Date();
    console.log(datetime.toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

Answer (score 16):

NodeJS (and newer browsers) have a nice [shortcut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) to get the current time in milliseconds.

```
var timeInMss = Date.now()
```

Which has a performance boost compared with

```
var timeInMss = new Date().getTime()
```

Because you do not need to create a new object.

Answer (score 10):

You would use the javascript date object:

[MDN documentation for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var d = new Date();
```

Comment: We can help the process along if we not only don't link to w3schools, but also DO link to the good results we want to see in Google.  [Good reference for javascript date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 9):

To create a new Date object in `node.js`, or `JavaScript` in general, just call it’s initializer

```
var d = new Date();

var d = new Date(dateString);

var d = new Date(jsonDate);

var d = new Date(year, month, day);

var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
```

Remember that Date objects can only be instantiated by calling `Date` or using it as a constructor; unlike other JavaScript object types, Date objects have no literal syntax

Answer (score 4):

GMT -03:00 Example

```
new Date(new Date()-3600*1000*3).toISOString();
```

Comment: This is the best answer until now. No need to install any new library when you only want to display or use the date in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is a server side JS platform build on V8 which is chrome java-script runtime.

It leverages the use of java-script on servers too.

You can use JS Date() function or Date class.

Answer (score 0):

I had an experience about dates on NodeJS with MongoDB database and I want to share it on this page as well,

I was setting a default value to a date field on Mongoose Schema as below code :

```
{ type: Date, default: new Date() }
```

but after one day, I've realized that default value is still getting date belong to yesterday.  it needs to be written as below :

```
{ type: Date, default: () => { return new Date() } }
```

Otherwise it always getting process start date , thanks to @lineus's comment on the page below :

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3675

Answer (score 0):

First, get the date

```
const date = Date()
```

create new date object

```
const new_date = new Date(date)
```

Then you can get all the details

```
const hours = new_date.getHours()
const minutes = new_date.getMinutes()
```