# How can I get the current date in nuxt from the server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was doing some code tests, but I need to get the current time from the server to run the tests.

In javascript you could do something like: `new Date ();`
To get the date from the client, but in nuxt to get it from the server side I can't think of how I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do exactly the same in a Node.js environment too: [How can I get date in application run by node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8559147/8816585)